# How generate get/set functions for related collections

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have some yml-configs:

```
#Story.orm.yml
pv\MyBundle\Entity\Story:
    type: entity
    table: story
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
```

And

```
pv\MyBundle\Entity\News:
    type: entity
    table: news
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: news_id
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    manyToOne:
        story:
            targetEntity: Story
            joinColumn:
                name: story_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

I want to add function `getNews` to `Story` for do something like `$story_entity->getNews()`
I had corrected oneToOne-relation:

```
manyToOne:
    story:
        targetEntity: Story
        inversedBy: news
        joinColumn:
            name: story_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

But when I try to run command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities --path=src/ MyBundle:Story
```

symfony doesn't update `News` entity and doesn't create function `getNews()`

How to generate this function? Maybe I make some errors?